# How to infer generic paramter in return type in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a type

```
export type AppThunk<ReturnType> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>;
```

Now If I use this as below

```
export const loadCourse = (id: string): AppThunk => {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    dispatch(loadCourseSuccess(undefined));
    return api
      .getCourse(id)
      .then((course) => dispatch(loadCourseSuccess(course)));
  };
};
```

The typescript compiler complains and tells me to provide a generic paramter in AppThunk, how to make it infer the generic return type parameter automatically?

Answer (score 0):

There's three different questions here:

- How to correctly define and use generic parameters in TS
- How to correctly define and use the `AppThunk` type
- How to possibly infer the right return type here

Right now, your `AppThunk` type expects that it *must* be given a generic parameter, `ReturnType`.  So, you *must* use it as `AppThunk<TheActualReturnType>` - in this case, something like `AppThunk<Promise<void>>`, because you're not really returning anything from the final `.then()`.

We typically recommend that the `AppThunk` type be given a default value for `ReturnType, since many thunks don't actually return anything, like:

```
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>;
```

That way, you can use it as `AppThunk` without having to specify the return type.

And finally... with the way `AppThunk` is being used, I don't immediately think it *can* infer the return type here, because you're *telling* TS what the type of this function is.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to provide a common type for the thunk parameters, but allow the action creator to infer it's return type, you can achieve that with a helper function:

```
export type AppThunk = ThunkAction<
  unknown,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>;

export function enforceThunkType<T extends AppThunk>(thunk: T) {
  return thunk;
};
 
// explicitly types dispatch
// while still infering the return type
export const loadCourse = (id: string) => {
  return enforceThunkType((dispatch) => {
    dispatch(loadCourseSuccess(undefined));
    return api
      .getCourse(id)
      .then((course) => dispatch(loadCourseSuccess(course)));
  });
};
```

[Inspired by / taken from this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/axrg5a/how_to_use_a_function_type_but_keep_inferred/ehvtoy5/)